# What are the tools helping writer polish the text to have it easier to understand?

Tags: editor

Some time ago I stumbled upon web application if a recall correctly that helped to work on text enhancing. Some of the features I recall:

- replacing difficult words by simpler synonyms;
- detecting complex, difficult to understand sentences (reducing cognitive load);
- correcting grammatical errors.
  There were some functionalities available for free but in general, it was paid application.

It was more advanced than Grammarly, LanguageTool and Hemmingway Editor.
Do you know such proofreading software?
I'm working on Linux, it is preferred to have a free application but paid one is also a viable option.

Comment: What OS shall it run on (or should it be a web app)? Must it be free, or what is the budget you'd be willing to spend?

Comment: I think you might be thinking about Autocrit.